# get information esim subscriptionManager.accessibleSubscriptionInfoList() always returns empty

Tags: android, flutter, apn

I am using the code below to get the Subscription Info(s) of all embedded subscriptions accessible to the calling app. But `subscriptionManager.accessibleSubscriptionInfoList` is always returned empty so I don't know how that works. Does anyone have the knowledge to help me fix this error?

```
     val subscriptionManager: SubscriptionManager =
                context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE) as SubscriptionManager
     val subscriptionInfos = subscriptionManager.accessibleSubscriptionInfoList
```